# Unity icons in Gnome-shell

Tags: unity, icons, ubuntu-gnome

Is there a way to get the current icons from Unity 7 into Gnome-shell?

I have tried to find a theme but couldn't find one with those icons.

Comment: Which icons do you mean exactly, the ones on the top panel bar, the icons displayed on the Dash?

Comment: every icon in gnome-shell, found the solution tough

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [this link](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance-Gnome?content=166632) for a theme

And also this one [which is](http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/heres-how-gnome-shell-can-look-like-ubuntu-unity) of a walk through of how to do what you are looking for.

More themes might be, becoming out with more unity like designs since Ubuntu is going to switch to gnome for it's default.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it worked using `sudo apt-get install light-themes`